# Why aren't all conditions checked in nested 'if statements'?

Tags: python, if-statement, conditional-statements, flowchart

```
score = 50

if score >= 60:
  print('elon')
  if score <= 50:
      print('please type number bigger than 0')
else:
  print('please type a number next time')
```

Can anyone try to help me understand the mechanics of why the second condition is met, but not executed, because it is nested behind a false first condition. I'm struggling with understanding how and when to nest "things". Why isn't the ELSE statement nested?

Comment: How could a number be both greater than 60 **and** less than 50? That is impossible.

Comment: the second if can only be reached if the condition of the first if is true. Use elif instead and don't indent it

Comment: Indentation is crucial in python. If on or other of the second `if` and the `else` were to have the opposite indentation they would be syntactically correct, but have a different meaning.

Comment: Everything inside the `if score >= 60` block is only run if the score is at least 60. So the `if score <= 50` statement is not even reached.

Answer (score 0):

Python uses indentation as block delimitation, but if you prefer we can make it explicit with C-style curly braces :

```c
score = 50

if (score >= 60) {
    print('elon')
    if (score <= 50) {
        print('please type number bigger than 0')
    }
} else {
    print('please type a number next time')
}
```

What this code does if checking if `score` is greater or equal than 60, if it is it will execute the content of the block, so `print("elon")` then checking if `score` is less or equal than 50, and if it is `print("please ...")`.
In this case, the nested `if` can never be true, because to make it here, `score` has to be greater or equal than 60, so it can not be lesser or equal than 50.

If I reduce the indentation of the nested if, and make it an elif :

```py
if score >= 60:
    print('elon')
elif score <= 50:
    print('please type number bigger than 0')
else:
    print('please type a number next time')
```

This means :
|score|result|
|------|-----|
|score <= 50|please type number bigger than 0|
|score >= 60|elon|
|50 < score < 60|please type a number next time|